# Query to sort through history table

Tags: join

[image]

I have the above tables and want a query that will give the results as above.

Basically I have a table of history where I want to display single row by adding two column that show prior Group from current Group in table A. In some cases, there will be multiple lines of history, so I just need to return the latest Finished date where not null.

Comment: I assume table B is some kind of history of table A, but what is the purpose of table C?

Comment: Was just thinking the same thing... I am confused by this question.

Comment: Please ignore Table C

Answer (score 0):

This will return all current TableA with previous Group info.

```
Select *,
         (Select top 1 B
          From TableB
          Where started < b.started
          Order by started desc) as PriorGroup,
         (Select top 1 Started
          From TableB
          Where started < b.started
          Order by started desc) as PriorGroupStarted,
From TableA a
Join TableB b on (b.id=a.id and b.finished is null)
```

Replace `top 1` with `limit 1` or equivalent for your rdbms.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll give this a try. I'm relatively new to SQL, and I didn't have a lot of time to dig into the syntax to come up with my own solution. We'll definitely carve out some time in the future to learn SQL.